# TypeError: Cannot interpret 'torch.uint8' as a data type

Tags: python, pytorch

Today I have started to learn Pytorch and I stuck here. The code piece in the comment raises this error:
`TypeError: Cannot interpret 'torch.uint8' as a data type`

For changing the data type of the tensor I used: `quzu_torch = quzu_torch.type(torch.float)` But this time I got this error:
`TypeError: Cannot interpret 'torch.float32' as a data type`

````
import numpy as np
import torch
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

quzu = np.array(Image.open('wool.jpg').resize((224,224)))

quzu_torch = torch.from_numpy(quzu)

plt.imsave('quzucuq.jpg', quzu)

# quzu_torch = quzu_torch.type(torch.bool)
plt.imsave('quzucuq_tensor.jpg', quzu_torch)```
````

Comment: pyplot is using numpy datatypes to work, you are passing torch datatypes, so you are getting errors.

Comment: I understand. How can I fix it?

Comment: inverse `torch.from_numpy`

Comment: or try `torch.as_tensor(quzu)`

Comment: To convert a torch tensor to a NumPy array, use `quzu_torch.cpu().numpy()` (the `.cpu()` call is to make sure that the tensor is detached from the GPU, in case you are using a non-CPU runtime).

Answer (score 0):

Just use the numpy array for the image don't convert it into a torch tensor.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).